# How to write special characters in Julia code

Tags: julia, special-characters

Recently I have seen Julia code like this with special characters:
[image]

How can I write Julia code like this? Do I need to have a special editor or can I do this also with e.g. Notepad++?

Comment: They're Unicode characters. Some editors let you enter them using a key combinations. If you work in the Julia REPL you can use backslashes - https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/unicode-input/ ...

Comment: See for notepad++ https://superuser.com/questions/576431/notepad-inserting-special-unicode-characters-in-utf-8

Comment: @Bill: Wow, this is quite complicated. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @daycaster: Thank you, this works. By the way, typing like e.g. \esh<Tab> also works with Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Also, Pluto.jl will do Julia's REPL completions.

Comment: Also emacs in julia mode does this. I think that some on-line editors as well but the one I just tried (github) didn't handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Julia *allows* you to use various Unicode symbols for variable and function names, and it makes sense in a lot of the scientific domains Julia is used in, making the code be more alike the scientific notation. (It's sometimes called "executable math" for this reason, though at this point it's more like "executable scientific notation".)

However, in any new code you write, it's not generally *necessary* to use these symbols, and you can write the code  with the basic ASCII characters. Julia language and its standard libraries always provide ASCII equivalents for the Unicode functions they use.

For eg., `⊻` is the XOR character, and you can write `2 ⊻ 11` to get the XOR of the two numbers. But you can also instead write `xor(2, 11)` to get the same result, and they're exactly equivalent to the language. It's considered good practice for external packages as well, to provide their interface in terms of ASCII-typable names to the extent possible, even if internally Unicode-only names are used.

With that said, if you find you do need to work with code that uses such Unicode symbols, there are a few options:

**Option 1: Autohotkey-script for converting LaTeX-like input to unicode characters.**

Usually, the way to enter these character in Julia is using LaTeX-like syntax, for eg. `\epsilon` for `ϵ`. [The AutoHotKey script provided here](https://gist.github.com/kbauer/e8fee6514d124d5961f51fd7ba571bfd) gives somewhat similar functionality, allowing you to type LaTeX-like input and converting it automatically into the corresponding symbols.

**Option 2: A copy-paste list of symbols**

This is pretty ad-hoc, but can work for situations where you just need to edit some existing code. You can use a clipboard manager like [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/), or Win10's [inbuilt one](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-activate-the-new-clipboard-functions-in-the-windows-10-october-2018-update/), to keep a copy of all the symbols the script uses. At any point, you can choose and insert the particular symbol you need.

**Option 2a: Copy-paste from the REPL/Jupyter/Pluto**

I'll put this option too here since it uses the clipboard as well. This makes use of the usual workflow for writing Julia code - you'll probably want to try out the code in the REPL or in a notebook anyway, so you can use the tab-completion features there, and then copy that code into your editor. Julia has a `clipboard` function too, so after trying out `median(sin.(-ℯ:0.01:π))` in the REPL, you can surround that in triple quotes and pass it to clipboard like this: `"""median(sin.(-ℯ:0.01:π))""" |> clipbaord` from the REPL itself.

**Option 3: Use  JuliaEditorSupport/julia-NotepadPlusPlus**

This is sort of the "official" option, but only the syntax highlighting file has been updated recently, and the quality and reliability of the Autohotkey script here isn't clear. I'd be hesitant to recommend this option.

**Option 4: Use a better supported editor**

It's hard to let go of familiar tools, but in this case, this is probably the most reliable option long term. [Julia for VSCode](https://julia-vscode.org/) is probably the best supported editor right now, but the plugins for Vim and Emacs are also pretty good. If VS Code is too heavy (and Vim and Emacs unfamiliar), you can also try the [plugin for Sublime Text](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/Julia-sublime) which should be both easy to use and light.